# jQuery.kinetic - How to pre-scroll to a position when page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using [jQuery.kinetic](http://davetayls.me/jquery.kinetic/) to allow a div to be scrolled within its parent div by dragging the mouse, much like the [demo on the author's site](http://davetayls.me/jquery.kinetic/). By default, when the page loads, the upper left corner of the inner div is aligned with the upper left corner of the parent div (meaning it's scrolled as far up and left as possible). Like this:

[image: default]

I would like to "pre-scroll" when the page loads a specific number of pixels over so that the inner div is roughly centered. Something like this:

[image: new]

I'm not seeing anything in the documentation about being able to specify a starting position for the inner div but it looks like the author of jQuery.kinetic built in a way to extend the plugin beyond the default functionality like this:

```
$.Kinetic.prototype.newFeature = function(options){
   // define the task
};
```

Then I can call that functionality:

```
// use the method
$('#elem').kinetic('newFeature', { options });
```

**Is there a way to set a position on page load that I'm missing? If not, how can I extend the plugin to do what I want?**

Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't work to just give inner div a negative `margin-left`?

Comment: @snookieordie - I'll double check in the morning but if it works like adjusting `left`, it'll move the image properly but keep me from being able to scroll back to the cut off portion.

Comment: @snookieordie - yep, that's all does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It took me forever to figure out that the Kinetic plugin has built-in abilities to manually scroll the container. It's not anywhere in the documentation, but through inspecting the plugin code I noticed that it has methods to control the x and y-axis scroll position.

In the file jquery.kinetic.js from line 458 to 475 (at the time of writing) the `scrollLeft` and `scrollTop` methods are defined. https://github.com/davetayls/jquery.kinetic/blob/master/jquery.kinetic.js#L458

You can use them on a container with an already active instance of Kinetic by calling the following methods:

```
$("container-selector").kinetic("scrollLeft", 50);
$("container-selector").kinetic("scrollTop", 480);
```

It's worthwhile to go through the Kinetic code and figure out how it works and what functionalities are available to use en lieu of a more fully fleshed-out documentation.